# Django create user instance without password field

Tags: django, authentication

Currently i am trying to make an app which doesn't require password for user login. But the user model has a password field in it. Is it possible to create user auth model with out password field with overriding or customizing? I'm using django 1.9.

Comment: Why do you need a user at all if theres no auth? Instead of modifying the user model, just make an auth backend that just returns true

Comment: I want use user insatnce in my project. For token authentication in django rest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible even through not recommended as accounts are not safe from intruders then, What are you probably looking for is custom authentication backend

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)